# element # 1 height changes, element #2 height changes

Tags: jquery

I have an element (image with id="forklift") and a div. I need the height of the div to be the same as the image. That's easy of course. What I can't figure out is how to make it responsive.

I can make it so once hte page loads, whatever the width of the image, that will be the width of the div. But when I start playing around with the width of the tab, the image shrinks/expands but the div height does not change with it.

Does that make sense?

```
$("#mainImageOverlay").height($("#forklift").height())
```

Comment: *"Does that make sense?"* ... No, not at all without a [mcve]

Comment: Whatever bro. Other guy answered my question perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only on resize, you can put your existing JS code into a function like `your_function()` and add `onResize="your_function()"` to the `body` tag.

Comment: Awesome. Such a simple answer, I love it!